# Where to/ how to call my resizeimage method

Tags: java, resize, bufferedimage, graphics2d, imageicon

Ok so I created a method that resizes an ImageIcon my question is how/ where do I call it in order to make the ImageIcon I want to resize to that size here it is thanks, and the method should work so anyone looking for a method that does resize you should be able to use it :)

```
    public static void resizeIcon(ImageIcon icon, int Width, int Height){
    Image geticon = icon.getImage();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(geticon.getWidth(null), geticon.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(geticon, 0, 0, Width, Height, null);
    ImageIcon resizedicon = new ImageIcon(bi);
    icon = resizedicon;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you save the resized image first .Then set the imageicon by resource as the resized image.

```
public static Boolean resizeImage(String sourceImage, String destinationImage, Integer   Width, Integer Height) {
    BufferedImage origImage;
    try {

        origImage = ImageIO.read(new File(sourceImage));
        int type = origImage.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB :  origImage.getType();

        //*Special* if the width or height is 0 use image src dimensions
        if (Width == 0) {
            Width = origImage.getWidth();
        }
        if (Height == 0) {
            Height = origImage.getHeight();
        }

        int fHeight = Height;
        int fWidth = Width;

        //Work out the resized width/height
        if (origImage.getHeight() > Height || origImage.getWidth() > Width) {
            fHeight = Height;
            int wid = Width;
            float sum = (float)origImage.getWidth() / (float)origImage.getHeight();
            fWidth = Math.round(fHeight * sum);

            if (fWidth > wid) {
                //rezise again for the width this time
                fHeight = Math.round(wid/sum);
                fWidth = wid;
            }
        }

        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(fWidth, fHeight, type);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);

        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.drawImage(origImage, 0, 0, fWidth, fHeight, null);
        g.dispose();

        ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "png", new File(destinationImage));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(""+ex);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then call

```
ImageIcon ico = new ImageIcon(destinationImage);
labelforIcon.setIcon(ico);
```